# Empirical multivariate probability integral transform

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, nonparametric, uniform-distribution, copula

Is there a 'simple' way to obtain a non-parametric empirical multivariate probability integral transform?

**Univariate case**

The probability integral transform relates to the transform of any random variables with continuous cumulative distribution function into an uniformly distributed random variables : Let $X$ be a random variable and $F_X$ its continuous cumulative distribution functions, then $F_X(X) \sim U(0,1)$.

Indeed $F_{F_X(X)}(x) = P\left(F_X(X) \leq x\right) = P\left(X \leq F_X^{-1}(x)\right) = F_X\left(F_X^{-1}(x)\right) = x.$

It can be conveniently estimated from a sample of real values $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ with rank statistics: $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{1}(x_i \leq x_j) = \text{rank}(x_j)/n$ yields values uniformely distributed in $U(0,1)$.

**Multivariate case**

Now consider a random vector $X = (X_1,\ldots,X_d)$ with marginal cumulative distribution functions $F_1,\ldots,F_d$. Using the probability integral transform we obtain $U = (U_1,\ldots,U_d) = (F_1(X_1),\ldots,F_d(X_d))$ whose joint distribution is the copula $C$.
The analogous of the probability integral transform for the multivariate case is the Kendall distribution function $K(t) := P(C(U) \leq t)$. We have $K(C(U)) \sim U(0,1)$.

From a sample $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ where $\forall j \in \{1,\ldots,n\}, x_j = (x_j^1,\ldots,x_j^d)$ are $d$-dim. vectors, I want to estimate $K(C(U))$ in a 'simple' non-parametric way like the one with rank statistics of the $x_j$ in the univariate case.

Comment: [This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/226935/algorithms-for-computing-multivariate-empirical-distribution-function-ecdf) may be relevant.