# Algorithms for computing multivariate Empirical distribution function (ECDF)?

Tags: empirical-cumulative-distr-fn, multivariate-distribution

One dimensional [ECDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function) is fairly easy to compute. When it comes to two dimensions and up, however, online resources become sparse and hard to reach. Can anyone suggest, define and/or present efficient algorithms (not ready made implementation) for computing multivariate ECDF?

Comment: This may well be a computer science question, but I think this is the best place to find an answer, let me know if I should look elsewhere. Thanks.

Comment: Is there really any fundamental difference?  Computing a univariate ECDF is equivalent to sorting the data.  Computing a multivariate ECDF is equivalent to sorting the data lexicographically.

Comment: @whuber, not exactly, as far as I know. For each data-point, `X(i)`, we need to count the number of points contained in the hypercube that is defined by it (from `-inf` up to and including `X(i)` in all dimensions). Lexicographical (dictionary?) sorting will not necessarily work here, as the data-points have to be compared in every dimension separately. E.g.: `(2,3,4)` will be lexicographically greater compared with `(1,2,15)`, but the hypercube that's defined by `(2,3,4)` will not contain `(1,2,15)` since `15>4`.

Comment: True, the correspondence is not that direct.  But one would exploit that sorting, or something like it, to build a point quadtree (or octree *etc*) with $O(n\log(n))$ effort.  You might want to investigate the computational geometry and spatial indexing literature for details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On further investigation, the following paper gives efficient algorithms for the k-D ECDF problem:

Bentley, J. L. (1980). [Multidimensional divide-and-conquer.](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=2264224381457511190) Communications of the ACM, 23(4), 214-229.

The main data structure introduced is known as a [range tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_tree), and is somewhat similar to a [k-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree), but uses a space-for-time tradeoff to achieve faster range queries. The author of the above paper, Jon Bentley (of Programming Pearls fame), is the inventor of both data structures.

Both are binary trees which recursively partition a set of $k$ dimensional points by splitting along a coordinate axis at the median. In a k-d tree the sub-trees of a node are split along the $d$-th dimension, where $d$ cycles through $1\ldots k$ moving down the  tree. In a range tree the sub-trees are always split along the *first* dimension, but each node is *augmented* with a $k-1$ dimensional range tree defined over the remaining dimensions.

At the time of this writing, the Wikipedia page for "Range Tree" linked above points to a CS lecture (Utrecht U.) comparing these two tree types from circa 2012. This suggests that these data structures are still essentially "state of the art". There is mention of an improved "fractional cascading" variant for range trees, but for the all-points ECDF problem this just allows the performance of Bentley's algorithm to be achieved via repeated queries of the range tree.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting paper! I think this is what I need re: k-d trees. Would be great to see alternative methods. Unless this one is the state of the art.

Comment: @AlexanderF. I updated my answer to better describe the algorithm (including a more "official" reference). It appears the approach is still close to state of the art.  For recent developments the key phrase appears to be "orthogonal range queries" if you want to investigate further.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if there is a more efficient way to compute the ECDF *at the data points*, but the following brute force approach should be efficient for computing the ECDF over the *data "grid"*. It is a simple generalization of the 1D version.

Assume you have a data set consisting of $N$ points in $d$ dimensions, given in the $N\times d$ matrix $X$. For simplicity I will assume that $X$ consists entirely of unique numbers (i.e. [general position](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_position)*). I will use [Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/) notation in the following pseudo-code, as it is how I thought of the algorithm, but I can expand on this if there is interest.

First compute

$[x_{:,k},I_{:,k}]=\text{sort}[X_{:,k}]$ for $k=1:d$,

where $I$ is the coordinate-wise rank matrix, and $x$ is the coordinate-grid axis matrix (both of size $N\times d$).

Then [rasterize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rasterisation) the data points into the implied data grid, computing an (normalized) histogram as
$P=\text{accumarray}[I,\frac{1}{N},N\times\text{ones[1,d]}]$.

Then integrate this "EPDF" in each dimension to give the ECDF:
$P=\text{cumsum}[P,k]$ for $k=1:d$.

Now $P_{i_1,\ldots,i_d}$ is the ECDF sampled at $x_{i_1,1},\ldots x_{i_d,d}$.

This algorithm takes time $\text{O}[N\log N]$ for each sort and $\text{O}[N^d]$ for each sum, so the total cost is $\text{O}[d(N^d+N\log N)]$. As the gridded ECDF itself has $\text{O}[N^d]$ elements, this should be essentially optimal.

(*The assumption of distinct points can be relaxed by using $\text{unique}[]$ instead of $\text{sort}[]$, along with a bit of book-keeping.)

Comment: You might be interested in learning about quadtrees and their higher-dimensional generalizations, which provide efficient ways to search Euclidean spaces for points.  They asymptotically use $O(N\log(N))$ resources, which is far better than $O(N^d)$ for $d\gt 1$.

Comment: @whuber I have some idea of these, (e.g. [k-d trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree)). I am not sure if there is a single "best answer" here? Typically for a problem like this, you will also specify what operations your abstract ECDF data structure should support (e.g. point queries, subspace integrals, updating with new points, etc.). This will help determine what implementation is best suited.

Comment: I believe it should be clear what operations need to be supported for an ECDF.  The minimal one is to evaluate it at any point in the space.  It is true that if one is going to build an ECDF dynamically, alternative approaches might be superior, but those issues appear to be beyond the scope of the present question.

Comment: @GeoMatt22, this indeed looks like a method for computing histogram and it may be fine in cases where approximation is "good enough". However, why use a method which is `O(N^d)` when the brute force approach in `O(d*N^2)`. Fro example, for now I don't have too large of a data-set so I use the following Matlab one liner to compute d-dimensional ECDF with `O(d*N)` storage complexity (`C(i)` is the frequency of data-point `Y(i,:)`):   
`arrayfun(@(i) sum(C(all(bsxfun(@le,Y, Y(i,:)), 2))), (1:size(Y,1)).');`

Comment: @AlexanderF. I am just used to doing gridded versions of CDFs for $d\leq 3$ I guess. (In my day job I do that op. quite frequently to resample piecewise-constant fields between different 3D grids while conserving mass.)

Comment: (+1) Not for giving an efficient algorithm, but for clearly explaining an inefficient one that helped me understand the problem.