# Simulating New Observations from a Empirical Distribution Function

Tags: probability, distributions, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn

Recently, I found out that it is possible to simulate new observations from an Empirical Distribution Function (EDF) . Suppose I collected some data (e.g. heights of baksetball players): $x_1, x_2,\dots,x_n.$

- I first create the standard EDF for this data
- To generate new observations from this EDF, I then generate some random number ("
  $p_1$") from a Uniform Distribution between $(0,1).$
- I then see between which "steps" of the EDF does this number "$p_1$" lies.
- After this, I use the "Linear Interpolation Method" (e.g. https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/dd/LinearInterpolation.svg) to find out to which value of "$x$" does "$p_1$" correspond.
- This value (e.g. "$x_p$") can then be considered to be a randomly generated data point belonging to the EDF.$

All in all, this looks like a very useful method for simulating new (and plausible) data points from the EDF without having to take the risk of incorrectly assuming some underlying parametric distribution of the data (although relying on the EDF might have issues with "robustness"). This means that we now have the ability to simulate additional data points from the same Data Generating Process as the data we collected, which might allow us to better test our statistical model.

This leads me to my question: The example above uses a Univariate EDF. I have read that it is also possible to construct Bivariate and Multivariate EDFs (e.g. https://www.research.manchester.ac.uk/portal/files/85606937/MEPDFR.pdf). Although this looks  quite complicated, do researchers ever attempt to fit multivariate EDFs to their data and then try to simulate new points from this EDF for the purpose of testing their models? Or is this just far too complicated with little added benefit?

Thanks!

Comment: This sounded like a method to generate random numbers given distribution, and could well be used in multivariate setting.  See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/226935/algorithms-for-computing-multivariate-empirical-distribution-function-ecdf

Comment: This may work tolerably well if the initial ECDF is based on a very large sample. But if the initial sample is small, then the newly generated values will be limited. // Roughly, it would be like trying to make a bootstrap CI from too small a sample (size $n$) by taking re-samples of size $m >> n.$

Comment: You do not "have the ability to simulate additional data points from the same Data Generating Process as the data we collected", as the interpolated points are not generated from the distribution behind the data. The proposal does not differ in essence from simulating from another kernel approximation.